# Is it possible to load a Scala/Spark PipelineModel by mlflow?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mlflow

I try to use [mlflow](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/_modules/mlflow/spark.html#load_model) to load a serialized Scala/Spark [PipelineModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/PipelineModel.html).

From [mlflow document](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.spark.html#mlflow.spark.load_model) it seems it only supports **Py**Spark. Is this the case?

Is it possible to load a serialized Scala/Spark PipelineModel in mlflow?

Answer (score 1):

MLflow has a Java client which can be called from Scala. See: https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/java_api/index.html

The Java client has less features than the Python client in that it does not have the concept of MLflow flavors. So it doesn't have a flavor-specific log_model/logModel - you have to use logArtifact.

Example:

- https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-examples/tree/master/scala/sparkml
  https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-examples/tree/master/scala/sparkml/src/main/scala/org/andre/mlflow/examples/wine/sparkml